# How to change next run time of any Windows task which is scheduled using C#

Tags: c#

I have a Windows application, I'm fetching all the Windows tasks which are scheduled. Now I want to change the `Next Run Time` of any particular task. I am using C#

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
  //Gets List Of Tasks in a folder. For Root Folder use backslash  

  TaskFolder taskFolder = ts.GetFolder(@"\");
  TaskCollection col = taskFolder.Tasks;

  foreach (Task t in col)
  {
    taskName = t.Name;
    cbJobList.Items.Add(taskName);
    lastRuntime = t.LastRunTime;
    nextRunTime = t.NextRunTime;

    TaskDefinition taskDef = t.Definition;
    ActionCollection actionCol = taskDef.Actions;
  }
}
```